# Azure Portal: Not able to add named caches

Tags: powershell, azure, portal, azure-caching

I'm trying to add some named caches to my new Managed Cache in Azure

I first *powershelled* the create command

`New-AzureManagedCache -Name "mycache" -Sku "Standard" -Memory 2GB -Location "West Europe"`

then added a new named cache in the portal, and changed some settings to the existing *default* one.
When I press *Save* it asks for confirmation, I say *Yes* and it keeps asking for confirmation no matter how oft I say yes.

It seems so start a task in background but nothings happens. (probably a bug)

Anyone with the same issue?
Do you know another way to manage this?

Regards,

Everton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue in the portal affecting certain browsers.  If you haven't already, please try this from Internet Explorer.